# Room "Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type": which method?

Tags: android, dao, android-room, kapt, android-architecture-components

```
Error:Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Using `Room` I'm getting this error and I'd like to find out which method causes it.

I have multiple `DAO`s, with approximately 60 methods in total, and this error just popped up after adding a method (copy&pasted from another one that worked perfectly, just changed the field to set).

I could post the whole class of `DAO`s, but **I'm asking for a way to know which method failed**. I tried with `Run with --stacktrace`, `Run with --info` and `--debug option`, but none of these show any valuable information.

The method I added is a `@Query` `UPDATE` with `Int` return type, as suggested in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Query.html)

> UPDATE or DELETE queries can return void or int. If it is an int, the
>   value is the number of rows affected by this query.

EDIT: I'd like to add that I tried deleting the method, bringing the DAO back to the working state, but it still gives me this error.

EDIT2: Adding gradle console output because unreadable in comments:

```
error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
2 errors

:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s
```

Comment: what is the full error message from gradle console?

Comment: @pskink added the full error message to the question

Comment: this is my method which compiles just fine: `@Query("SELECT * FROM user") LiveData<List<User>> loadUsers();` when i change `List` to `Vector` for example i am getting: `UserDao.java:19: error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
    LiveData<Vector<User>> loadUsers();` in the **Gradle Console** window of android studio - note it shows `UserDao.java:19` which is a line location and also it prints the method that is wrong, more https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#gradle-console

Comment: I'm building from Kotlin, maybe that's why I don't get the line?

Comment: imho what you posted here is not gradle console output, are you sure you copied that error message from [gradle console](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#gradle-console)?

Comment: Edited question with gradle console output

Comment: @DavidCorsalini Did you find any solution, I am also facing the same issue

Comment: @user3853169 clean re-build fixed the error for me.

Comment: just to be sure. Are you returning `LiveData<T>` or `MutableLiveData<T>`?

Comment: I encountered the same issue today (return type was rxjava2 Observable). The error message does not contain any info about where the problem could be. I hope google will make the error message more informative. At least it should print a method name or expected return type...

Comment: File -> Project Structure -> Suggestions
informed me of some updates, did that, fixed.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I Spend the entire day on this issue. the solution was very simple. I was using something like this before

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM myTable")
fun getAll(): MutableLiveData<ArrayList<myData>>
```

Now when I changed ArrayList to **List** & MutableLiveData to **LiveData** it is working fine.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM myTable")
fun getAll(): LiveData<List<myData>>
```

based on the answers & comments on this issue I think room support only List & LiveData because I tried with on MutableLiveData & only ArrayList too. none of the combinations worked.

Hope this will help someones few hours.

Comment: In my case, I was using suspend.

Comment: This issue can occur for a lot of reasons, mine for ex. was updating Kotlin to 1.5. When I reverted to 1.4.32 the issue disappeared.

Answer (score 155):

Recently I've had the same problem but I was using `Coroutines` within the `Dao` function, e.g.:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Dummy")
suspend fun get(): LiveData<List<Dummy>>
```

And was unable to compile, but after **removing the `suspend`** everything worked just fine. It's not needed when returning `LiveData`. `suspend` and `LiveData` seem not to work together (as of now).

Comment: For `Co-routines` support, I added `implementation "androidx.room:room-coroutines:${versions.room}"` dependency, but Build failed saying **`ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.room:room-coroutines:2.2.1'**.

Comment: This was my issue. When returning LiveData, you should not use a suspend function because they are incompatible (and not needed).

Comment: @iCantC You can just import `implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"` which is the up-to-date variant on how to integrate coroutines support for Room. See also official docs: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room

Comment: it is good to know, Yeah it was the cause of my problem for me also. Thx.

Comment: FYI "room-coroutines" has been renamed to "room-ktx" as of [Version 2.1.0-alpha05](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.1.0-alpha05). However, I already had this in my project and it did not fix the error. Removing `suspend` as per this answer did fix the error for me.

Comment: You answer saved my day. By reading android documentation i  converted my DAO function to suspend function. Now i have to convert it back as non Suspend

Comment: This link confirms this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54566663/room-dao-livedata-as-return-type-causing-compile-time-error

Answer (score 56):

For anyone landing here, using a [coroutine Flow](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130428884) as a return type, you will get this error if you accidentally make the function suspend. Since it is returning a flow, there is no need to suspend.

So instead of this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = :id")
suspend fun findById(id: Long): Flow<MyDataType>
```

use this (without suspend modifier):

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = :id")
fun findById(id: Long): Flow<MyDataType>
```

Comment: You saved my day!

Comment: @gMale As it's no longer a suspended function, should i call `.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)` while collecting the `Flow` ?

Comment: I have the same error even without returning a Flow. It seems there is a bug related to the suspend function, it used to work.

Comment: But it solved when I replace the `kapt` for the `ksp`. So if using Kotlin suspend function, use `ksp`.

Comment: @theapache64, Very late response, and you probably know by now, but for future readers, there is no reason to tag the function with `flowOn`. It would be terrible design if the API returned you a Flow that didn't already run on whichever thread/dispatcher pool it needed to for safe use, just like it would be terrible design (and against coding convention) for an API to expose a suspend function that has to be called on a specific dispatcher to be used safely. Room correctly handles both cases and internally uses the correct dispatchers.

Comment: @Tenfour04 ack..

Answer (score 39):

Yup, based on what you have mentioned in the comments, you are not allowed to change the return type from `List` to anything else inside the `Dao`. I'd assume Room doesn't know how to deal with other return types. Take the `List` and cast/convert it into your desired type outside of the `Dao`.

Answer (score 16):

There is an issue related to a change in Kotlin's `@Metadata` annotation and the way Room reads it, `Room 2.4.2` is using an older version of the `kotlinx-metadata-jvm` library which does not support reading `Kotlin 1.7.x` information, whereas in `Room 2.5.0` google updated the library.

To work around this issue please force upgrade the dependency by adding it to your annotation processor path, i.e. add `kapt "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.5.0"` if you are using `Room 2.4.x`.

or you can use `Room 2.5.0-alpha02` it will solve the problem.

### Conclusion

if you just want to solve the error add this to app/gradle file

```
kapt "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.5.0"
```

or use these versions of room with `Kotlin 1.7.x`

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.0-alpha02'
kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0-alpha02'
```

[source](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/5/issues/236612358)

### Update

Now you can use updating the Room version to `Room 2.4.3` with `Kotlin 1.7.10` without any problem.

Comment: Thanks so much fixe my problem. We need also implement multidex. `    // Room
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0"
    kapt "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.5.0"`

Comment: You are welcome, implementation depends on your kotlin version and room version which will make you choose which dependencies to implement. in my case, I used room 2.4.2 and kotlin 1.7.10.

Comment: updating room to 2.4.3 solve my problem with kotlin 1.7.0

Comment: Yes, now Room version 2.4.3 solve the problem that was in 2.4.2. Thanks @diAz

Answer (score 12):

It is gone after I updated to latest version Room - room_version = "2.4.0"

Answer (score 8):

```
@Query("select * from movie_action")
    suspend fun getMovieActionRoom() : LiveData<List<MoviesActionModel>>
```

just remove suspend  and the error will be gone in some cases.

Answer (score 6):

In my case i was this problem when i used  `LiveData<ArrayList<Example Class>>` in Dao class for getting  all things from Room and i fixed this when i change `ArrayList` with `List`.

Example(Kotlin):

```
@Dao
interface ExampleDao {
@Query("SELECT * from example_table")
fun getAllExample():LiveData<List<Example>>
}
```

Comment: if you wanted to be able to modify your `LiveData<List<Example>>` without getting this error then change it to `LiveData<MutableList<Example>>` .

Comment: that because Room is returning a different implementation of List, but you are trying to force it into an ArrayList.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I started getting the error after upgrading to Kotlin 1.9 and Room 2.5.2. I got solved by switching room compile from kapt to ksp.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was using `androidx` dependencies for `Room` and `android.arch.` [old] dependencies for `ViewModel` and `LiveData` so I got this message

**Solution:**
Either use all `androidx` dependencies OR use all old dependencies of `andrio.arch`

Answer (score 2):

For me it was because of mixing AndroidX with Pre-AndroidX. After a full migration and [performing this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52225655/2506817), everything was back to normal. (Of course I moved to AndroidX-Room as well)

Answer (score 2):

I've got a different use case for my apps.

So, I'm trying to return the actual `Cursor` type.

E.g:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM tbl_favourite")
abstract suspend fun selectAll(): Cursor
```

The above code will always throw `Error:Not sure how to convert a android.database.Cursor to this method's return type`

But as I recall correctly, the official docs also stated [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-cursor) that **Room** supports `Cursor`.

After trying to debug the error log, and open up the `MyTableDao_Impl.java` file I've found that looks like `Cursor` are having an unhealthy relationship with `suspend` keywords.

Thus, I've corrected my code to be like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM tbl_favourite")
abstract fun selectAll(): Cursor
```

And voila, it works.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure if there is

> There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing
>   database (no such table: METRO)

error in your build log before the error you mentioned in your description. If it is, you may have forgotten to add your new entity Pojo to database class. something like this

```
@Database(entities = {Table.class,ForgottenTable.class}, version = 1) 
public abstract class Database extends RoomDatabase {
    //class codes
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in case someone actually needs `MutableLiveData<List<T>>` in their ViewModel when working with `Room` and using `Kotlin` and `coroutines`, this is how I've solved it

In the Dao I get MutableList with `suspend`
In the repository I change the context to `Dispatchers.IO` and extract the list with `suspend`
in the ViewModel I use `postValue` with the list in the init, syntax is below

ViewModel

```
    private val allItems = MutableLiveData<List<DocumentItem>>()
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            allItems.postValue(repository.getAll())
        }
    }
```

Repository

```
    suspend fun getAll(): MutableList<DocumentItem> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        dao.getAll()
    }
```

Dao

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM document_items ORDER BY id DESC")
    suspend fun getAll(): MutableList<DocumentItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

For my case, after got "Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type”:

delete the "build" and re-build, the error disappear.

Comment: lol that fixed quite some errors which didn't made any sense! Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not using suspend together with LiveData as return type:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM ...")
fun getAllTellsByReceiver(receiverUid: String): LiveData<List<Tell>>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case upgrading versions worked.

Previous

```
api 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.0.0'
api 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.0.0'
```

Now

```
api 'androidx.room:room-runtime:+'
annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:+'
api 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:+'
```

`+` means latest version and for me it was 2.4.2

Answer (score 1):

In my case, package line at the top of the file wasn't correct

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code inside defaultConfig in build.gradle

```
javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true
```

Comment: care to explain why?

Comment: We want to have an explanation about this as this solution did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class IdAndFullName {
     public int uid;
     @ColumnInfo(name = "full_name")
     public String fullName;
 }
 // DAO
 @Query("SELECT uid, name || lastName as full_name FROM user")
 public IdAndFullName[] loadFullNames();
```

If there is a mismatch between the query result and the POJO, Room will give you this error message.

Or if you are using @SkipQueryVerification, you will also get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your Dao, use Flowable instead of observable and add the following dependency (room with rxjava support)

```
compile group: 'android.arch.persistence.room', name: 'rxjava2', version: '1.1.1'
```

Dao returns flowable:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM TableX")
public abstract Flowable<List<EntityX>> getAllXs();
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was using wrong return type for queries.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the @Relation annotation in the class returned by the method. It's the only way Room would know how to establish the relationship between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason this might occur is if you try using ArrayList instead of List as it doesn't recognize the return type if it has ArrayList.

for example use:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM notificationTable ORDER BY id ASC")
fun getAllNotifications(): LiveData<List<UserNotification>>
```

instead of

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM notificationTable ORDER BY id ASC")
fun getAllNotifications(): LiveData<ArrayList<UserNotification>>
```

Answer (score 0):

For my situation, I removed my base **Resource** class from my Dao, because of it doesn't know how to change the Resource class, and it worked.

**Before**

```
fun getAll(): Flow<Resource<List<SavedCharacter>>>
```

**After**

```
fun getAll(): Flow<List<SavedCharacter>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by upgrading my room version

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion"
```

upgrade room version from **roomVersion = '2.3.0'** to **roomVersion = '2.5.2'**

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I was implementing the paging 3 library.
I solved it by updating my Room dependency version to the latest stable one and also added room-paging support:

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-paging:$room_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use suspend and LiveData together. I was also getting same error when I'm writing this

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM saved_articles")
suspend fun getAllSavedArticles() : MutableLiveData<List<Article>>
```

Also Use **LiveData** not **MutableLiveData**. this might also cause an error

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM saved_articles")
fun getAllSavedArticles() : LiveData<List<Article>>
```

Answer (score -1):

For me it was to change from MutableLiveData to LiveData as the return type of the get method.

Answer (score -1):

I got this error when I was trying do some aggregate functions in the query, like sum and count and then using aliases in the column names.

`select count(users.id) as userCount, ...`

It so happens that the alias name like `userCount` above, **must match** the field name in the model.

Answer (score -1):

In my case Room didn't know  sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type i.e `ArrayList`
so I changed a little bit I converted to list to kotlin's `MutableListOf`. Now it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

This error goes away after I changed the Kotlin version from 1.5.21  back to 1.3.61

Comment: This doesn't provide a solution to the issue. The cause of the issue needs to be identified. Downgrading Kotlin version is never a solution.