# Failed to resolve variable '${animal.sniffer.version}' when migrate to AndroidX

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, androidx, android-studio-3.2

I'm using **Android Studio 3.2 Beta5** to migrate my project to **AndroidX**. When I rebuild my app I got these errors:

> ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${animal.sniffer.version}'
>
> ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${junit.version}'

Full clean & rebuild did not work! Anyone know how to fix this?

---

**gradle.properties**

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-beta05'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.3.1"
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.iceteaviet.fastfoodfinder"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
        }
    }
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-rc01'

    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'

    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

    implementation 'io.realm:realm-android-library:5.3.1'

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0'

    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.2'

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'

    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'

    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Any progress here?

Comment: @ChadBingham No, it still be the same error

Comment: Finally found the solution, please find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52308912/10224384

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52294319/why-is-butterknife-9-0-0-snapshot-not-resolving

Comment: @Nabster hey hey my question was posted a month ago while this question was posted 20 hours ago!

Comment: Same problem here with Android Studio 3.2 stable version. Invalidate cache restart only temporarily fixed this issue

Comment: @nboxbypass you must select an answer ! :)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

I fix this with two steps

1) File -> Invalidate Caches / restart...
[image]

2) Build -> Clean project
[image]

Comment: Somehow worked for couple of rebuilds but Im getting same error again now..

Comment: for me Clean Project have been just enough

Comment: Also Clean Project was all that required for me. Thanks @f4bo for the tip.

Comment: It works. I only clean project. This answer should be set as accepted answer. @nhoxbypass

Answer (score 35):

I got the same error after updating my build.gradle file with [AndroidX Test dependencies](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project#gradle-dependencies). Turns out I forgot to remove the old junit dependency. So for me, the fix was simply to remove the following dependency:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: This was the problem for me.

Comment: Yep fixed it. I ran into the issue with the Udacity Kotlin course guess it game

Comment: Could you please explain why this is the case?

Answer (score 17):

Adding **Java 8 support** to **build.gradle** file fixed issue for me

```
android {
     ...

     //Add the following configuration in order to target Java 8.
     compileOptions {
         sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
         targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
     }
}
```

Comment: leanback not found. im building a TV app and it goes red on anything regarding on  leanback support v17

Comment: invalidate caches and restart android studio

Comment: no its not, I figured you gotta use the androidx package.

Comment: I guess adding Java 8 support forces Android Studio to invalidate it's caches and thus achieves the same result as a side-effect... Hmmmm, alright...

Answer (score 14):

It seems to be **Glide** the problem.

I had the same error and I just updated the Glide's dependencies to 4.8 and there is no build errors.

**Kotlin :**

```
// Glide
def glide_version = "4.8.0"
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"
kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glide_version"
```

**Java :**

```
// Glide
def glide_version = "4.8.0"
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"
annotationProcessor "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glide_version"
```

Be sure to have enabled in your gradle.properties :

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Source : https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/3124

Hope this will help you!

Comment: This error also appears to me without having Glide as a dependency

Answer (score 7):

Fixed it by going to the main directory and typing `flutter clean`

Comment: Great, what if you're not using flutter ;)

Comment: @KevinGalligan Then use Flutter ;)

Answer (score 6):

Removing the testInstrumentationRunner worked for me:

```
defaultConfig {
...
...
//        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Comment: fantastic solution! Fixed it for me

Answer (score 4):

If you're using `Kotlin`, the issue will popup if don't use the `kapt` version for any annotation processor you use in the project.
As @Vince mentioned the case with `Glide`, this could happen with `Dagger2`, `Butterknife`, etc.
If you're using both `Java` and `Kotlin` you'll need to keep both dependencies, as follows (were `$glideVersion` is a predefined version of `Glide`):

```
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glideVersion"

kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glideVersion"
```

If you're on a `Kotlin` only project, the `kapt` dependency should work alone.

**EDIT**
Another thing you should have in mind is if you're already using `Androidx`. `Androidx` is a great refactor but when migrating it can cause some of your dependencies to collapse. Mainstream libraries are already updated to `Androidx`, however, some of them are not and even won't.
If the issue doesn't go away with my provided solution above this edit, you can take a look at your dependencies and make sure they use `Androidx` as well.

**EDIT 2**
As @Ted mentioned, I researched back and he's right `kapt` does handle `java` files as well. `kapt` alone will do the trick, no need to keep both `kapt` and `annotationProcessor` dependencies.

Comment: kapt can also handle java files, so no need to use them both, just only kapt is OK.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing this line:

```
maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
```

from the buildscript / repositories section of your build.gradle file.

When I added that line, I got the error you described. When I removed it, no longer. That line should only be in the allprojects / repositories section.

Comment: I believe Jake Wharton already added support for AndroidX in 9.0.0 snapshot. See: https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/1280

Answer (score 2):

Try set android.enableJetifier=false in gradle.properties. Then Invalidate Caches / Restart ... in Android Studio

Comment: It's not recommended since there could be third-party libraries which weren't upgraded to AndroidX yet! As the documentation says: "android.enableJetifier: When set to true, the Android plugin automatically migrates existing third-party libraries to use AndroidX by rewriting their binaries. The flag is false by default if it is not specified." https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/

Answer (score 2):

The fix is in 4.2.0, use the higher version of google gms jar.

Try changing:

> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

by this version:

> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

Hope this works...

Comment: This worked for me along with updating dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using dagger or butterknife, please make sure to update it to the latest version. Or, if you have another injection library used in your project, you can try to check it if it support androidx or no.

I've found same error, the problem is on my dagger and butterknife. Have fixed it by updating it to newest version.

Answer (score 1):

Android version: 4.10.2

I solved this issue with three simple steps:
First i added below this in pubspec.yml:
(with two spaces of identation)

```
module:
  androidX: true
```

Adding this two lines below in gradle.properties, i have this in android/gradle.properties, in the project folder.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

And after this i wrote with the terminal:

```
flutter clean
```

Maybe you will have to stop the device and run again.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by updating the firebase dependencies to the latest.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error after adding butterknife to my project.

In order to resolve this error you should use Java8.

I would recommend [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54566532/5145150) answer.

How I resolved it:

1.add following code in build.gradle (module: app)

```
android {
  ...
  // Configure only for each module that uses Java 8
  // language features (either in its source code or
  // through dependencies).
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

2. clean prject and run.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by refreshing the cahche (Instead of invalidating it - which also clears the local history):

1. in gradle.properties file, comment the line org.gradle.caching=true.
2. Clean, Rebuild.
3. in gradle.properties file, un-comment the line
       org.gradle.caching=true.
4. Clean, Rebuild.

Thats it!

Answer (score -1):

Go to file and click on Invalidate caches and restart.

After it restarts then you increase the minimum SDK version in your app's `build.gradle` file.