# Why is butterknife 9.0.0-SNAPSHOT not resolving?

Tags: android, androidx, butterknife

I want using AndroidX library and below is my Gradle setup for Butterknife

**app:module Dependency**

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
 annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

**Plugin**

`apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'`

**Project Dependency**

```
dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha09'
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
      classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
      // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
      // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

**Project Repository**

```
repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
        jcenter()
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of All, I'd like to acknowledge @intellij-amiya and @Nabster valuable contribution as this answer is based on the ones they provided.

My Gradle setup is as follows

```
...
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
....
dependencies{
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
...

    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            name 'Sonatype SNAPSHOTs'
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha09'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            name 'Sonatype SNAPSHOTs'
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 18):

**UPDATE:**
You can now simply use ButterKnife 9-rc02 instead of the above mentioned solutions:

```
...
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-rc2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-rc2'
...
```

---

Based on the answer from Naveen, the solution is [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/1280). 
However, there are missing details. Please refer the below Gradle configurations for the complete solution:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            name 'Sonatype SNAPSHOTs';
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and

```
...
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
...
```

Basically, don't use `apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'` and `classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'` from the suggestion [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/1280).

Also, this Android Studio Settings > Compiler configuration:
[image: Android Studio Settings > Compiler configuration]

Comment: This solution needs to be updated when the butterknife 9 is in production.

Answer (score 9):

Please note that Butterknife has now reached 10.1.0 and there's no longer need for SNAPSHOT versions or any other maven libraries. AndroidX migration works as a charm. Just include:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'
}
```

or, if for some reason you're combining Kotlin and butterknife, replace `annotationProcessor` with `kapt`.

For more information, visit: 
https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife

Answer (score 4):

Add  **`name 'Sonatype SNAPSHOTs';`**

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3' //3.1.4

    }

    buildscript {
            repositories {
                google()
                jcenter()
                mavenCentral()
                // TODO remove after butterknife 9 graduates to stable
                maven {
                    name 'Sonatype SNAPSHOTs';
                    url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
                }

            }
```

**FYI**

You can use

```
   implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
   annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

Read [**`Butter Knife`**](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife)

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your response.
I'm now getting this error.
error: package android.support.annotation does not exist 
error: cannot find symbol class UiThread 
error: cannot find symbol class CallSuper

Comment: @Ismail using `:butterknife:8.8.1` ?

Comment: Yes. the generated ViewBinding class keeps importing annotation from android package instead of androidx package

Answer (score 1):

See that conversation about conflict between Butter Knife 9.0.0-SNAPSHOT and Android studio 3.0.
https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/1145

Answer (score 0):

also add support Java 1_8 in
**build.gradle** in **android** section

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow instructions for GitHub repository  which worked for me 100% with the latest version  [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife):

Answer (score 0):

Android studio Flamingo and above butterknife library not supported to R.id.imageview but in my lot of research i got succeed with below code

```
 1. 
android {
  ...
  // Butterknife requires Java 8.
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'
  annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'
}

 2. To use Butter Knife in a library, add the plugin to your buildscript:

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:10.2.3'
  }
}

 3. and then apply it in your module:
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'

 4. Now make sure you use R2 instead of R inside all Butter Knife annotations.
class ExampleActivity extends Activity {
  @BindView(R2.id.user) EditText username;
  @BindView(R2.id.pass) EditText password;
...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'
```

It's working in androidx