# AndroidX and FirebaseFirestore gives java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, androidx

I've just started migrating a project over to use Firebase and AndroidX, and so far as I can tell I'm having to do something that I shouldn't: I have had to downgrade the classpath for google-services.

What mistake have I made that means I can not use the latest version (4.1.0)?  I have a working app, so I'm not too upset, I'd just like to know what I've done wrong!

The error I get with the latest 4.1.0 version:

```
09-25 20:54:38.152 5311-5311/com.iainism.joebot E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.iainism.joebot, PID: 5311
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.iainism.joebot/com.iainism.joebot.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.iainism.joebot. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.iainism.joebot. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:219)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:49)
        at com.iainism.joebot.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:32)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

-- project buidle.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
}
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha11'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'  //4.1.0 Crashes app on start

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

-- app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.iainism.joebot"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

-- MainActivity.java:

```
package com.iainism.joebot;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.multidex.MultiDex;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // TODO: Add authentication
    // TODO: Change security rules

    // TODO: Rework content provider to do all CRUD via Firestore

    private DocumentReference mDocRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document("FirstGo/Test");

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set-up Toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Set-up FAB
        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.floating_action_button);

        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FAB clicked!");
                // TODO: add proper action
            }
        });

        // Set up Firebase Firestore
        Map<String , Object> cloudData = new HashMap<>();
        cloudData.put("data", "This is a test!");

        mDocRef.set(cloudData).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
               if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                   Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Created Firestore document");
               } else {
                   Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Failed to create Firestore document", task.getException());
               }
            }
        });

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Reached end of onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings: {
                // TODO: Rebuild settings menu...
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "You selected Settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Settings menu selected");
                break;
            }
            // case blocks for other MenuItems (if any)
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

-- In gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX = true
android.enableJetifier = true
```

Comment: I noticed that you're using "alpha" grade software in your top-level build.gradle. What if you use the fully released `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0` instead?

Comment: Good point.  I'm eventually going to (re)introduce ButterKnife and use of `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha11` is required for this with AndroidX (plus a 9.0.0-SNAPSHOT of Buttknife itself): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52294319/why-is-butterknife-9-0-0-snapshot-not-resolving/52308912#52308912

However, this morning I spotted that even though I just updated to AS3.2, there's already an update available for the Android SDK Build-Tools.  I've applied this and the issue seems to have gone away - so it looks as though I might have found a real bug, with a pending fix.

Comment: "Buttknife" - oops - too late to edit now; of course, I meant "Butterknife"!

Comment: That bug sounds problematic.  So does Buttknife.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even while I hit this problem with a freshly updated Android Studio 3.2 installation, it seems that Google were already preparing a new version of Android SDK Build-Tools.  After finding, and applying this update this morning, the runtime error is no longer present when using `com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0` (with no other changes).

Moral of the story:  Give up sooner and come back the next day to see if something's been patched overnight in the tooling that resolves the problem!

Answer (score 0):

> Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process
>   `com.iainism.joebot`. Make sure to call
>   `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context)` first.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'  //4.1.0 Crashes app on start
```

`Multidex` is also enabled. I didn't see it. You can however try to disable it then checking with google services(*latest version till now*):

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

Then calling:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(MainActivity.this)
```

And declaring `DocumentReference` inside `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Firebase initializes itself automatically when `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` is present along with the Firebase config file.  No one should have to call this function manually in this case.

Comment: Well you're right and that's a good point. However, already knew that if `apply plugin` is present, we wouldn't have to initialize the firebase manually but, that's what IDE suggested. Anyways, OP mentioned that when he/she uses 4.1.0 of the google services crash happens. Perhaps the multidex causes the issue. Sounds weird tho. Thanks for mentioning BTW.

Comment: The IDE didn't make this suggestion.  It's a crash at runtime.  There might be some strange interactions with the plugin along with other newer tools available for Android builds (somehow a ContentProvider got removed?), but I personally have no ideas where to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

it reads:

> Default `FirebaseApp` is not initialized in this process `com.iainism.joebot`.
>
> Make sure to call `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context)` first.

set `private DocumentReference mDocRef = null;` ... in order to follow the instruction above:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this.getContext());
this.mDocRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document("FirstGo/Test");
```

else you'd access the `FirebaseFirestore` before initializing the `FirebaseApp`.

Comment: I understand this, but why does the message occur with 4.1.0 and not 4.0.0?  Also, so far as I can find in the docs, direct use of `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context)` is not supposed to be needed, and is generally frowned upon.

Comment: Also, as pointed out by @Doug Stevenson in a comment on another answer: "Firebase initializes itself automatically when `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` is present along with the Firebase config file. No one should have to call this function manually in this case."