# Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am quite baffled here. So maybe someone can shed some light for me. I have what seems to be a simple pattern (full code below), and yet I am getting compiler error saying

> error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return
>   type.

What's the problem? I am on `room_version = "2.1.0-alpha02"`

```
@Entity(tableName = "big_dog")
class BigDog(val big: Boolean, @PrimaryKey val id:Int=1)

@Dao
interface BigDogDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(dog: BigDog)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM big_dog LIMIT 1")
    fun getBigDog(): LiveData<BigDog>

}
```

Comment: I have already looked here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445964/room-not-sure-how-to-convert-a-cursor-to-this-methods-return-type-which-meth?rq=1) and I have already tried returning `LiveData<List<BigDog>>`. I still get the same error.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Check the logs when you deploy to see if there are any notifications besides this error. If there are go through and fix them. It is possible to get this error if there is something wrong somewhere else wrong with your room code.

For my specific problem it was that I accidentally added a duplicate variable to one of my entities.

```
public int routeId;
/* other code */
public int routeid;
```

This caused this warning to pop up in the build log.

> Room cannot create an SQLite connection to verify the queries. Query verification will be disabled. Error: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (duplicate column name: routeId)

I went through and fixed everything up so there was no warnings and Query verification was re-enabled and I no longer got

> error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type.

Comment: This is a valuable answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check your app gradle file. Try don't mix Pre-AndroidX and AndroidX components dependencies in your project.
Pay attention to dependencies namespace group. They should have a similar beginning.
In my example it's `"android.arch.____:X.X.X"`

```
dependencies{
   ...

   def lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"
   def room_version = "1.1.1"

   // Lifecycle components
   implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
   annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$lifecycle_version"

   // Room components
   implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
   annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
}
```