# Room Dao LiveData as return type causing compile time error

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, android-architecture-components

I am using **Room** and implemented **Dao** that returns `LiveData`. It was working fine with below dependency added.

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha04"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0-alpha04"
```

But when I added new Room coroutine dependency as mentioned below.

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha04"
implementation "androidx.room:room-coroutines:2.1.0-alpha04"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0-alpha04"
```

Below is code which compiles

```
@Dao
interface AccountDao{

    @Query("SELECT * FROM account_master")
    suspend fun getAllAccounts(): List<Account>
}
```

Below is the code which gives error.

```
@Dao
interface AccountDao{

    @Query("SELECT * FROM account_master")
    suspend fun getAllAccounts(): LiveData<List<Account>>
}
```

started to receive error.

```
PlayGround/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/playground/www/x/datasource/dao/AccountDao.java:11: error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (androidx.lifecycle.LiveData<java.util.List<com.playground.www.x.datasource.entity.Account>>).
public abstract java.lang.Object getAllAccounts(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

Any one facing similar issue?

Comment: I guess you don't need to use `LiveData<List<Account>>` as return type. Try return `List<Account>`: `suspend fun getAllAccounts(): List<Account>`

Comment: I want my data to be observable , so I need it to be LiveData, which was working fine before. Started to give error after adding "implementation "androidx.room:room-coroutines:2.1.0-alpha04""

Answer (score 22):

I think the solution here is actually to just **return the LiveData without using Coroutines**. LiveData works out of the box, there's no reason to use Coroutines when returning LiveData.

When using LiveData it already handles it on a background thread. When NOT using LiveData then in that case you can use Coroutines (and maybe eventually Coroutines Channels) or RxJava2.

See this codelab for an example: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin. Here they need a background thread for inserts but not for the returned LiveData.

Note: there seems to be a mistake in the actual codelab where the DAO is not returning a LiveData. I've corrected that in the sample below.

```
@Dao
interface WordDao {

    @Query("SELECT * from word_table ORDER BY word ASC")
    fun getAllWords(): LiveData<List<Word>>

    @Insert
    suspend fun insert(word: Word)

    @Query("DELETE FROM word_table")
    fun deleteAll()
}

class WordRepository(private val wordDao: WordDao) {

    val allWords: LiveData<List<Word>> = wordDao.getAllWords()

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun insert(word: Word) {
        wordDao.insert(word)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure using LiveData it will automatically handle it on background thread ??.

Comment: Yes. You can see this codelab as an example. In this case they only need a background thread for inserts but for the returned LiveData it is not necessary. I added the codelab to the answer.

Comment: @Pinakin did you get a chance to try this out?

Comment: This works asynchronously because declaring LiveData<Foo> as return type of a Dao, will trigger the use of a RoomTrackingLiveData during code generation and that will use of an executor that will work on a background thread.

Answer (score 15):

Remove the suspend function. LiveData is already asynchronous. No need for a suspend function.

```
@Dao
interface AccountDao{

    @Query("SELECT * FROM account_master")
    fun getAllAccounts(): LiveData<List<Account>>
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Current implementation of **Room** doesn't support **coroutines** with `LiveData` (we can't define a function to be `suspend` and return `LiveData` at the same time). As a workaround you can implement it like the following:

```
@Dao
interface AccountDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM account_master")
    suspend fun getAllAccounts(): List<Account>
}

class AccountRepository(private val dao: AccountDao) {

    suspend fun getAccounts(): List<Account> {
         return dao.getAllAccounts()
    }
}
```

And in your implementation of `ViewModel` class you can create `LiveData` object and assign a value to it, retrieved from DB:

```
class MainViewModel(private val accountRepository: AccountRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val _accounts: MutableLiveData<List<Account>>
    val accounts = _accounts // To access it from Activity/Fragment

    fun loadAccounts() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            accounts.value = accountRepository.getAccounts()
        }
    }
}
```

To use `Dispatchers.Main` import:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.1.1'
```

---

Or you can directly return `LiveData` without marking the function as `suspend`:

```
@Dao
interface AccountDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM account_master")
    fun getAllAccounts(): LiveData<List<Account>>
}


class AccountRepository(private val dao: AccountDao) {

    fun getAccounts(): LiveData<List<Account>> {
         return dao.getAllAccounts()
    }
}

class MainViewModel(private val accountRepository: AccountRepository) : ViewModel() {

    val accounts = accountRepository.getAccounts()

}
```

---

Another approach to get notified when the changes to the DB occur is to use `Flow<List<Account>>` as a return type of `getAllAccounts` method:

```
@Dao
interface AccountDao{

    @Query("SELECT * FROM account_master")
    fun getAllAccounts(): Flow<List<Account>>
}

class AccountRepository(private val dao: AccountDao) {

    fun getAccounts(): Flow<List<Account>> {
         return dao.getAllAccounts()
    }
}

class MainViewModel(private val repo: AccountRepository) : ViewModel() {

    fun loadAllAccounts(): Flow<List<Account>> = repo.getAccounts()

}

// In Activity/Fragment

lifecycleScope.launch {
   viewModel.loadAllAccounts().collect { accounts ->
       // use accounts, for example populate RecyclerView Adapter
   }
}
```

Comment: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-coroutines-422b786dc4c5. Room supports coroutines now

Comment: Right, in my answer I meant we can't define function to be `suspend` and return `LiveData` at the same time.

Comment: i agree with the answer posted

Comment: @Sergey I got the behaviour by doing such code changes and I come to know the limitation.
But I didn't find any official supporting document.

Answer (score 4):

As Michael Vescovo pointed out, there are two possible ways of achieving async call:

```
@Dao
interface AccountDao{
    @Query("SELECT * FROM account_master")
    suspend fun getAllAccounts(): List<Account>
}

@Dao
interface AccountDao{
    @Query("SELECT * FROM account_master")
    fun getAllAccounts(): LiveData<List<Account>>
}
```

Which one you'll use depends on your use case. For example, I would use the first one if my DAO consumer (usually repository) will create LiveData for the model (in the case that I don't need to observe changes from local DB).

If I need to observe changes in local DB (for example, some other service can update DB in the meantime) I would use the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Not same, but similar. RoomWordSample CodeLab worked fine until I updated Android Studio and then Gradle plugins.

The failing code is below from the WordDao class. Flow was not recognized.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM word_table ORDER BY word ASC")
fun getAlphabetizedWords(): Flow<List<Word>>
```

I had used the following import, which worked before, but was failing after the updates.

```
import kotlinx.util.concurrent.Flow
```

I had to change the import statement as follows:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
```

I also made quite a few dependency changes too, but Coroutine change was likely needed for this fix.

```
ext {
    activityVersion = '1.4.0'
    appCompatVersion = '1.4.0'
    lifecycleVersion = '2.4.0'
    coroutines = '1.5.2'
    roomVersion = '2.3.0'
}

dependencies {

implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$rootProject.appCompatVersion"
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$activityVersion"

// Dependencies for working with Architecture components
// You'll probably have to update the version numbers in build.gradle (Project)

// Room components
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$rootProject.roomVersion"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
implementation 'androidx.room:room-common:2.3.0'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.2'
implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

// Lifecycle components
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"

// Kotlin components
//implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.0'
api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$rootProject.coroutines"
api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$rootProject.coroutines"
```

}

Another failure was due to missing @Dao annotation.