# Room LiveData not observing changes on inserts and updates

Tags: android, kotlin, android-listview, android-room, android-livedata

I have setup a simple ROOM instance in Kotlin as follows:

MODEL:

```
@Entity(tableName = "postinfo")
data class PostInfo(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int = 0,
    var title: String? = null,
    var content: String? = null
): java.io.Serializable
```

DB:

```
@Database(entities = [PostInfo::class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun postInfoDao(): PostInfoDAO
}
```

DAO:

```
@Dao
interface PostInfoDAO {
    companion object {
        const val tableName = "postinfo"
    }

    @Query("SELECT * FROM $tableName")
    fun getAll(): LiveData<List<PostInfo>>

    @Insert
    suspend fun addPost(postInfo: PostInfo)

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tableName")
    suspend fun getPostCount(): Int

    @Query("DELETE FROM $tableName WHERE rowid in (select rowid FROM $tableName LIMIT 1)")
    suspend fun deleteFromTop()

    @Query("DELETE FROM $tableName")
    fun clear()
}
```

Now, I have a `ListView` in my `MainActivity` (I do not want to use `RecyclerView` and `ViewHolder`, and I am not using fragments or view models - I just want this to be a simple app), and a custom `PostAdapter` for the list view. I want to observe changes to the DB so that whenever it changes, the adapter gets updated and the change is seen on screen. Here is the code that I am using to observe the DB:

```
val adapter = PostAdapter(this)
binding.listView.adapter = adapter

notiDAO.getAll().observe(this) { // 'this' is the MainActivity context
    runOnUiThread {
        adapter.clear()
        adapter.addAll(it)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

This works as intended only if I clear the DB or if I use `notiDAO.deleteFromTop()`. But whenever I insert a new record into the DB, the observer doesn't get triggered and the list view doesn't get updated (I have also tested with `@Update` and `@Upsert`, those don't work either). The code in the observer only runs in the beginning when I declare the observer in `onCreate` or when I delete a post, but not when a new post is added.

Why is this? Can what I'm trying to do even be achieved without using things like `RecyclerView`, `Fragment` and `ViewModel`s?

Edit: Adding the piece of code for adding new post, as requested:

```
override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
    // val post = ...
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        notiDAO.addPost(post)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share how you are adding the post?

Comment: If you want a dirty solution without having to think a lot, just delete and print the database again after you add an element

Comment: @Darshan I am adding the post in a notification listener service. I have added the code in the question. Your comment got me thinking, and after messing around with the code, I have found that it is indeed the source of the problem. If I add the post in the MainActivity itself, then it does work! But I can't figure out why it doesn't work from the service.

Comment: @AnchithAcharya since you are trying to implement it on service have you tried using suspend functions instead?

Comment: @AashisShrestha As you can see in the DAO code, I have made the addPost method suspendable. This is what you mean right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @AnchithAcharya I think suspending the getAll function and storing the result in a MutableLiveData variable should help so that you can observe the variable instead of directly observing the query. addPost method is fine.

Comment: @AashisShrestha getAll cannot be a suspend function as it's returning a LiveData object. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54570374/6455667) for more details

Comment: @AnchithAcharya Yes, exactly what I was suggesting you, the workaround mentioned in [link you provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54566663/room-dao-livedata-as-return-type-causing-compile-time-error/54570374#54570374) instead of using Coroutine with LiveData