# Android Room Kotlin throws Delete Query error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm trying to use Android Room 2.3.0 and I'm currently getting the compile errors below:

ProjectDao:

```
error: Not sure how to handle query method's return type (java.lang.Object). DELETE query methods must either return void or int (the number of deleted rows).
    public abstract java.lang.Object deleteAllProjects(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
error: Query method parameters should either be a type that can be converted into a database column or a List / Array that contains such type. You can consider adding a Type Adapter for this.
    kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> continuation);
error: Unused parameter: continuation
    public abstract java.lang.Object deleteAllProjects(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
    kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super java.lang.Long> continuation);
error: Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.
    public abstract java.lang.Object insertProject(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
error: Not sure how to handle delete method's return type. Currently the supported return types are void, int or Int.
    public abstract java.lang.Object deleteProject(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
    kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> continuation);
```

CounterDao:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

However, my ProjectDao.kt file has the following:

```
@Dao
interface ProjectDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM table_projects")
    fun getAll(): List<Project>

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertProject(project: Project): Long

    @Insert
    fun insertProjects(projects: List<Project>)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteProject(project: Project)

    @Query("DELETE FROM table_projects")
    suspend fun deleteAllProjects()

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM table_projects")
    fun getAllProjectsWithCounters(): List<ProjectWithCounters>

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM table_projects WHERE id_project=:projectID")
    fun getProjectWithCounters(projectID: Long): ProjectWithCounters
}
```

I've not had any issue with this previously, and all of a sudden I'm getting these errors and I've no idea what could be causing them.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a dependency on `room-ktx`? Please include your `build.gradle`

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73105048/12173531) should help you.

Answer (score 19):

**Update**
room version: 2.4.3
Kotlin: 1.7.20

This solves the problem.

Answer (score 10):

Set kotlin version is 1.5.21  or 1.5.31
Kotlin 1.6.0 cannot use `suspend` in ROOM `@QUERY`
Choose one of the following solutions

1. open your root build.gradle and add this
   `classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21'`
2. open your module build.gradle and change **room-version** one of 2.4.0-alpha03 until 2.4.0-beta01
   `def roomVersion = "2.4.0-alpha03"`

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem as follows

I set Kotlin version to **1.6.10** than Room to **2.4.2**

Answer (score 2):

With the `@Delete` annotation, you have to define a return data-type:

> DELETE query methods must either return void or int (the number of deleted rows).

So this should rather be:

```
@Delete
suspend fun deleteProject(project: Project): Integer
```

This would return `1` on success and `0` when the `project` didn't exist in database.

Comment: If the method return is not explicit that would be `Unit` which is then compiled to Void?

Comment: This is actually an `interface` definition - and the error message renders your argument invalid. If this would be the case, it wouldn't demand to have return types `Integer` or `Void` defined - from which the actual methods are being generated.

Answer (score 2):

It was a problem with the specific room + kotlin combination.
As of writing this post you can correct it to:

```
def room_version = 2.6.0-beta01
```

also, if you should upgrade your gradle plugin to:

```
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21'
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73105048/12173531) should help you.

Answer (score 1):

As an **update** you can now change your room version to `Room 2.4.3` with `Kotlin 1.7.10` and every thing will be fixed

Answer (score 1):

**This error occurs when you use suspend keyword in the room @dao entity, remove suspend keyword from @dao class**

```
@Dao
interface ProjectDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM table_projects")
    fun getAll(): List<Project>

    @Insert
    fun insertProject(project: Project): Long

    @Insert
    fun insertProjects(projects: List<Project>)

    @Delete
    fun deleteProject(project: Project)

    @Query("DELETE FROM table_projects")
    fun deleteAllProjects()

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM table_projects")
    fun getAllProjectsWithCounters(): List<ProjectWithCounters>

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM table_projects WHERE id_project=:projectID")
    fun getProjectWithCounters(projectID: Long): ProjectWithCounters
}
```

By default, all methods of room entity are already asynchronous in the latest room version.

or update the room version to 2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing `suspend` before trying other more efficient methods. I came across a similar problem. and was suggested by a senior to try to remove it and the project is going well till date

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found two solutions and both of them work for me :

**First solution** :

- use `room_version = "2.6.1"`
- use `compileSdk = 34` and `targetSdk = 34`

**Second solution**

change kotlin version

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
```

it works with the room version

```
room_version = "2.4.3"
```