# Android: Kotlin Room how to take unique data from table and use this in recycle view

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room

I have a table with lessons and I need to select all the unique group names from there to display them in the recycle view

Lesson data class

```
@Entity(tableName = "lesson_table")
data class Lesson (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "lesson_name") val lessonName: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Group_name") val groupName: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "day") val day: Int?
)
```

LessonDAO

```
@Dao
interface  LessonDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM lesson_table")
    fun getAll(): List<Lesson>
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT Group_name FROM lesson_table")
    fun findallgroup(): List<Lesson>
```

And this in fragment code to inset data in rcview

```
  private fun init(){
        binding.apply {

            gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
            rcView.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
            rcView.adapter=adapter

        }
        GlobalScope.launch { adapter.addItems(appDb.lessonDao().findallgroup())}
    }
```

It doesnt work, but if I use getAll() from DAO its works
Please help

P.S. if I use findallgroup() i get that error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
    Process: com.example.calendar2, PID: 5833
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `GlobalScope`. You should use a lifecycle scope so it is bound to the Main thread, which is required when working with any UI components. A lifecycle scope also automatically cancels its coroutines when the view is destroyed, which avoids leaking memory or causing crashes that could happen when trying to reference views that no longer exist.

In an Activity:

```
lifecycleScope.launch { adapter.addItems(appDb.lessonDao().findallgroup()) }
```

In a Fragment:

```
viewLifecycle.lifecycleScope.launch { adapter.addItems(appDb.lessonDao().findallgroup()) }
```

Comment: Thank you for help, bu if I use this
`
        lifecycleScope.launch { adapter.addItems(appDb.lessonDao().findallgroup()) }
`
i got this error
`
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
`
it in fragment 
pls help

Comment: Oh, I missed noticing this in your code. If using coroutines, you should define any DAO functions as `suspend` if they aren’t returning LiveData or Flows. This allows them to be safely called from any dispatcher and not block. The non-suspending way you defined it means they block the calling thread, which means they have to be called on Dispatchers.IO, but then you have to switch back to Dispatchers.Main to safely work with UI. So it is much easier to just make them suspend.

Comment: yep, but now i get error which i fixed week later
`Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (java.lang.Object).
    public abstract java.lang.Object findallgroup(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()`

this is my project ` https://github.com/Gelio3455/Calendar2`

Comment: Are you mixing `suspend` with `LiveData` or `Flow`? Not sure if your latest checked in code includes your attempt. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445964/room-not-sure-how-to-convert-a-cursor-to-this-methods-return-type-which-meth

Comment: Could also be a version mismatch (https://stackoverflow.com/a/73105048/506796). Make sure you update Room and the Room compiler and Kotlin to the latest versions.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed it. i just make new implementation in gradle & added suspend
`
 def room_version = "2.5.0"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"

    // To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
`